# How to find out the user ID of the command/request sender when we use any IPC (Inter Process Communication) in PHP?

Tags: linux, security, php, webserver

Currently, We use socket for Inter process communication between two process  , the application is written in PHP.

Our scenario is, there is a server (server.php) and multiple PHP clients. 
We want perform certain task based on the client, certain clients have certain restrictions. When client sends the request to the server(server.php), How can the server finds out, Which (linux user ID) user sends the request ?

If it is not possible by socket, is there any other methods ?

Comment: You could give each different process a (secret shared) key to identify it to the server

Comment: I think the receiver can still get the credentials of sender if IPC using UNIX domain socket. See   SCM_CREDENTIALS on http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html But notice this is syscall interface, PHP may not support that natively, you might want an extra php syscall module

Comment: SCM_CREDENTIALS may work in c, not in PHP. This requirement is in PHP.  Providing key is not an option here.